# Is there a DRYer way to initialise class values in C#?

Tags: c#, object, dry

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Foo
    {
        private int blah;
        private char bleh;
        private string bluh;
        //...
        public Foo()
        {
        }
    }
```

Now normally, I have to initialise it like this:

```
    public Foo(int blah, char bleh, string bluh,...)
    {
        this.blah=blah;
        this.bleh=bleh;
        this.bluh=bluh;
        //...
    }
```

This is dull and doesn't seem to follow the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle so I'm looking for a better solution. Can this be done DRYer?

Edit: Changed variables to private to reflect a more common use case.

Comment: *"This is dull and doesn't seem to follow the "Don't Repeat Yourself""* How?

Comment: You have a bug. You're using fields instead of properties. Fix the bug. As for DRY - nothing violates DRY here

Comment: The DRY principle has nothing to do with your example.

Comment: You could use a record type, `public record Foo(int blah, char bleh, string bluh,...)` and it will assign the variables to blah, bleh, bluh and so on. It lets you create an entire class as a 1 liner.

Comment: A record in C# 9 would help only if you need a record - ie an immutable type with value semantics. It would also fix the serious bug of exposing a class's internals to others instead of using properties.

Comment: @Cid I have to write down the same this.<variable>=<variable> boilerplate code a bunch of times.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is just an example code. I have already replaced it with a struct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The example is immutable so I assume that is what they are after.

Comment: This is not what DRY means. DRY is about tangible pieces of logic, not about variable initialisation.

Comment: @DorijanCirkveni "example code" that doesn't represent the actual question helps nobody. There's no DRY issue in your code. All those changes do is confuse people and cause downvotes for answers that don't deserve them. Ben's answer was good for your *initial question*. It no longer matches the changed question

Comment: After the change, the code won't even compile

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The example code is made after a class I had since rewritten as a struct. My question is independent of whether the variables are private or public. Should I revert the question to its original state and ask a separate question?

Comment: @DorijanCirkveni there's no repetition. A constructor with parameters means the parameters are required. A constructor does more than assign values too.

Comment: @DorijanCirkveni instead of posting an example something like the actual problem, post the *actual code* that causes repetition. There's no repetition in this code. What is the actual problem? What are you trying to solve? Is the *real* problem the way struct values can be copied when modified perhaps? Is that why readonly fields were used instead of readonly properties?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay. What do I do with this question? Do I edit the actual code in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use object initialization when initializing your variables/properties instead, if you really don't want to **repeat yourself**

Like this

```
Foo f = new foo{
    blah = 1;
    bleh = 'A';
    bluh = "something";
};
```

And also, don't use public accessor on your fields, that's not good.

Comment: There's no DRY to begin with. A parameterless constructor means all properties are optional and allows partially initialized classes or structs with defaults

Comment: This answer doesn't remove the (nonexistent) repetition, it changes what the class allows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think he doesn't want to use the constructor just to not really "repeat himself" so I used object initialization just to remove the initialization on his contructor and the parameters.

Comment: You didn't remove the constructor call. You called the parameterless constructor and then assigned values to the already constructed object. `new foo{}` is equivalent to `new foo(){}`. You can even use parameters, if such a constructor is available, eg `new foo(abc){...}`

Comment: There's no repetition to remove in this question. The question shows confusion about DRY - or the question's example has nothing to do with the real problem

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo
{
    public readonly int blah;
    public readonly char bleh;
    public readonly string bluh;
    //...
    public Foo(int blah, char bleh, string bluh)
    {
        this.blah=blah;
        this.bleh=bleh;
        this.bluh=bluh;
        //...
    }
}
```

Can be written as a record type and is a good candidate as its immutable. To rewrite the above as a record just use

```
public record Foo(int blah, char bleh, string bluh);
```

Much cleaner in my opinion and seems to be what you're after.

Comment: A record does more than just make the constructor cleaner. This may have knock-on consequences. You should only use records if you want immutability. It's not clear if this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Liam in first example, before editing the question, and when Ben posted this answer, OP used `readonly` fields, which would indicate a possible immutable class

Comment: `readonly` is not the same as immutability

Comment: @Liam A readonly field can't have its value changed after it is created.